# Weird c++ input escaping and space behavior

Tags: c++, console, user-input

I'm having an unpleasant problem with my c++ example. Everything works fine until I enter something with a whitespace.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true) {
        char * input = new char[256];
        scanf("%s", input);
        cout << ++iteration << ": " << input << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So with this code, I can enter anything, but everything after whitespace is somehow like stored in buffer and used in the second iteration.

```
foo
1: foo
bar
2: bar
foobar
3: foobar
foo bar
4: foo
5: bar
```

Every single input reading function acts like this and it's driving me crazy. `cin >> input`, `freads()`, `cin.get()` etc. all do this.

It this frequent problem with user input, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please observe you never delete your memory; you leak every iteration. If you're hardcoding the size (and it's a small size), I don't see the purpose in even dynamically allocating it. Just do `char input[256]`. In any case, if you actually needed dynamic arrays, use a `std::vector`. What you really want is `std::string`, though.

Comment: @GMan Thank you, next time I'll do better.

Comment: Indeed. Basically, avoid dynamic allocation as much as possible. And when you do need it, use a class that will free it automatically to ensure you never leak. (Like `vector` and `string.`) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, never use `scanf`. It's difficult to use that function and avoid buffer overflows. Replace `input` with a `std::string`, and read from `std::cin`.

Both `scanf("%s", input)` and `cin >> input` will read one word, delimited by whitespace. If you want to read a whole line, then use `getline(cin, input)`.

Answer (score 1):

About [`scanf %s` format specifier](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/):

> This will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab).

About [`istream::operator>>` with str parameter](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

> Extraction ends when the next character is either a valid whitespace or a null character, or if the End-Of-File is reached.

So yes, this is standard behaviour for these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using std::getline instead?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/